# Powershell Converting datetime object to string - How to display time in non-military format?

Tags: .net, powershell, datetime

Say I have a variable called $d, which converts a date as a string to a DateTime object:

```
$d = [datetime]"1-2-14 1:25pm"
```

I can convert that object back to a string by doing:

```
"{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm}" -f [datetime]$d
```

But this outputs the 'hh:mm' in military time. Is there a way to get it to output the time portion in non-military time with the am/pm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [format specifier for the AM/PM designation is "tt"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-tt-custom-format-specifier):

```
"{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt}" -f $d
```

If you want 24-hour time instead, substitute `HH` for the hours:

```
"{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}" -f $d
```

The cast to `[datetime]` is unneccessary, `$d` is already of type `[datetime]`

Comment: It's not return seconds! do you know how I should return seconds too?

Comment: If you follow the link in the answer and scroll up two sections, you will see that you can use `ss` for that 